# Error when deleting a entity associated to another entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I've got a event entity and a feature entity. Those two entities are associated to each other by a one to one mapping:

EventInstance.php:

```
/**
* @ORM\Table(name="event_instance")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\EventInstanceRepository")
*/
class EventInstance
{
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Feature", mappedBy="eventInstance", cascade={"all"})
 */
private $feature;
...
}
```

Feature.php:

```
/**
* Feature
*
* @ORM\Table(name="feature")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\FeatureRepository")
*/
class Feature
{
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="EventInstance", inversedBy="feature")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="eventinstance_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
 */
private $eventInstance;
...
}
```

If i try to delete a feature, which is referenced to a event, using the following code:

```
public function deleteAction($id, Request $request)
{
    $feature = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AppBundle:Feature")->find($id);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->remove($feature);


    $em->flush();
    // this response, because the action gets called in the event detail in a fancybox
    return new JsonResponse(array("success" => true));
}
```

i get a error message:

```
EntityManager#remove() expects parameter 1 to be an entity object, NULL given.
```

I've verified, that the find method actually returns the Feature entity, so the $feature variable is not null. dump of a feature:

```
FeatureController.php on line 128:
Feature {#770 ▼
  -id: 35
  -title: "aa"
  -description: "<p>sss</p>"
  -linkText: null
  -validFrom: null
  -validTo: null
  -eventInstance: EventInstance {#821 ▶}
  -medias: PersistentCollection {#820 ▶}
  -created: DateTime {#766 ▶}
  -updated: DateTime {#767 ▶}
  -createdBy: User {#534 ▶}
  -updatedBy: User {#534 ▶}
}
```

Is there something wrong with my mapping? I have no idea why this error comes up.

Comment: `@ORM\JoinColumn(name="eventinstance_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")`  and you get `EntityManager#remove() expects parameter 1 to be an entity object, NULL given.`  I'm no Doctrine expert, I actually detest it but that's a story for another day.

Comment: I guess, that onDelete=set null isn't really necessary. But even when I remove it, the error remains.

Also i should mention that the entity do gets deleted, even though the error gets thrown.

Comment: Can you post the dump of the Feature ?

Comment: i added the dump of a feature to the question

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i've had some js code in my website which reloaded the feature delete page. The feature got deleted correctly, then the page got reloaded and the error got thrown. Sorry to have bothered you all.